# Unrecognized selector sent to instance and crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selector, uistoryboardsegue

I'm working with storyboards in xcode and during the prepareForSegue method it crashes. What i want to do is from a tableview to come to another detailed tableview after i click on a cell. Here is the code.

GamesInfoViewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
    DetailViewController2 *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSUInteger row = [myIndexPath row];
    GameInfo *gameInfoObject;

    gameInfoObject =[GamesInfoArray objectAtIndex:row];
    detailViewController.DetailArray = @[gameInfoObject.HomeTeam, gameInfoObject.AwayTeam];  // IT CRASHES HERE!!!
}

}
```

And here is DetailViewController2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

[self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
GamesInfoTableViewCell *cell = (GamesInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

cell.mainLabel.text = _DetailArray[0];
cell.awayTeamLabel.text = _DetailArray[1];

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
```

}

DetailViewController2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController2 : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DetailArray;
@end
```

AND YES i have selected DetailViewController2 as custom class in storyboard!!!

Error Message: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setDetailArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa65a537f00'

Comment: Please post the selector that wasn't recognized.

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: Added to the bottom of the question!

Comment: Is DetailViewController2 a subclass of UINavigationController or is it embedded in a UINavigationController?

Comment: it is a subclass, would it matter?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the segue is creating a UINavigationController instead of your custom class. Double check your storyboard ;)

Comment: @F1ank3r it is pretty clear that `DetailViewController2` is a subclass of `UITableViewController` as they had already shared that part of the code. On `DetailViewController2 *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];` it's returning a `UINavigationController` and not a `DetailViewController2`

Comment: Correct, i needed to specify a custom class for the segue i don't  now know that since its my first time thanks!!

Comment: It worked. Please look at the comment below KiDdAe's answer. Its giving me an error message is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this line

```
DetailViewController2 *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

returns an `UINavigationController` and not a `DetailViewController2`

If `DetailViewController2` is embedded in an `UINavigationController` You probably want to do something like :

```
UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
DetailViewController2 *detailViewController = (DetailViewController2  *)navController.topViewController;
```

if `DetailViewController2` is a subClass of `UINavigationController` you may have forgotten to explicitly say it in your Storyboard.

Comment: It worked with your code but it gives me an error why is that?

Incompatible pointer types initializing 'DetailViewController2 *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *' @KIDdAe

Comment: I edited my answer to remove this warning.
You got it because the compiler knows that `navController.topViewController` is an `UIViewController` but at this point it can't be sure that it is also a `DetailViewController2` so it is warning you that you could have an error here.

Answer (score 1):

`KIDdAe`s is totally correct `DetailViewController2 *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];` is returning a `UINavigationController` and not a `DetailViewController2` my answer is more of a clean up of your existing code and I'll also add in the answer.

**GamesInfoViewController.m**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        // [segue returns a UINavigationController and the controller you 
        // want is embedded in the navigation controller
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];

        // We want the top view controller from the navigationController
        // and don't forget the cast
        DetailViewController2 *detailViewController = (DetailViewController2 *)navigationController.topViewController;



        // Removed redundant line as there was no need to create local variable for
        // one time use
        NSUInteger row = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

        // There was no need to have these two on on separate lines
        GameInfo *gameInfoObject = [GamesInfoArray objectAtIndex:row];

        // To add a fail safe you could wrap this in respondsToSelector
        // just in the event that the topViewController isn't a DetailViewController2 
        if ([detailViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setDetailArray:)]) {
            // Note the lowercase for detailArray see comments above this property.
            detailViewController.detailArray = @[gameInfoObject.HomeTeam, gameInfoObject.AwayTeam];  
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailViewController2.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController2 : UITableViewController

// Properties and ivars start with lowercases classes have uppercases
// try to stay to coding conventions it will help you and others when needing help
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *detailArray;

@end
```

**DetailViewController2.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   GamesInfoTableViewCell *cell = (GamesInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

   cell.mainLabel.text = _detailArray[0];
   cell.awayTeamLabel.text = _detailArray[1];

   // Configure the cell...

   return cell;
}
```

If you read the comments within the answer you will see why I have changed things for the better. If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Beautiful :), Thank you for commenting on why you did things. Just one question that might not be related to your code but if i have another tableview that would show the exact same thing as DetailViewController2. Would i have to make another navigation controller with a tableview  same as DetailViewController2 or can i hook it up to the same class?